# Trying to make a AngularJS animation work

Tags: angularjs

I have an example of an animation of 2 forms, where the first is hidden and the other is shown when a button is clicked (and reversed when cancel is clicked). See http://plnkr.co/edit/asJ9u7MwRwMECpGaX3uz?p=preview

I want to make a AngularJS version of this. I am trying to adapt to a John Lindquist tutorial on the subject: http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-animating-the-angular-way

But now I am stuck. How can I make the second form initially hidden and how can I make it behave like the jQuery only example (in the proper Angular way)?

The code, as you can see on http://plnkr.co/edit/Z4UYp1m3moVlarzbBNnO?p=preview, has the following html:

```
<h1>Testing animation with AngularJS</h1>
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
  <form ff-toggle-animation="!main.showNewUserForm" role="form">
    <input type="text" id="search" ng-model="main.username" size="30" placeholder="New username here">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="main.showNewUserForm=true">Add</button>
  </form>
  <form ff-toggle-animation="main.showNewUserForm">
    Username:  <input type="text" id="add" ng-model="main.username" size="30" placeholder="New username here"><br>
    Full name:  <input type="text" ng-model="main.name" size="30" placeholder="Add new user full name here"><br>
    Description: <textarea id="description" rows="2" ng-model="main.description" placeholder="Add user description here"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" ng-click="main.save()">Save</button>
    <button type="submit" ng-click="main.showNewUserForm=false">Cancel</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

And this is the script I have so far:

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function () {
  this.users = {};
  this.showNewUserForm = false;
  this.save = function() {
    // some code to save a new user
  }
});

app.directive("ffToggleAnimation", function ($animate) {
  return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.ffToggleAnimation, function(newVal) {
      if(newVal) {
        $animate.addClass(element, "show");
      } else {
        $animate.removeClass(element, "show");
      }
    });
  }
});

app.animation(".show", function() {
  return {
    addClass: function(element, className) {
      $(element).toggle(400);
    },
    removeClass: function(element, className) {
      $(element).toggle(400);
    }
  };
});
```

There is a reason why I want 2 forms instead of extending the first form, but this example does not relay that reason.

Comment: use `ng-show`  will remove about 90% of the code you are presenting. Button toggles a boolean in scope....one form is set to show for true, other for false or can be set to specific value in scope variable

Comment: In my script I am using a JavaScript animation (jQuery.toogle), is it possible to use JavaScript animations with ng-show?

Comment: I am now trying to do a ng-show version. But I cannot see how this removes 90% of the code? With css-animation you get a huge number of lines of css-code, with JavaScript animation (without the directive as I have tried here) perhaps you can get away with not so many lines. But I cannot see how this can be reduced so much as you indicate. Perhaps you could give an example or explain it a little better? I might very well have misunderstood something (new to Angular and JS in general), it would be cool to be able to do this with much less code (like the 7 lines in the jQuery-only example).

Comment: you don't need second directive.... or add the class show in first directive. `ng-show` can be managed by an `ng-clcik` handler in controller